# show boundaries only in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps API V3, is it possible to show only state boundaries and nothing else?

I've tried using google.maps.MapTypeStyleFeatureType and turning off all the features, but I am still getting way more than I want.

Even with mapType=Road you still see topographic information.

How can I get just a simple boundary map with nothing else showing?

Answer (score 1):

Trying using this style object, hopefully it is what you are looking for.  There are many sites which allow you to customize your style using a GUI.  [Try this one](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter)

```
  [
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "poi",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "transit",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "road",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "administrative.country",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "administrative.country",
      "elementType": "labels.text",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "administrative.province",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "on" }]
  },{
      "featureType": "administrative.province",
      "elementType": "labels.text",
      "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]
  }
]
```